# How to disable and enable a radio button at the same time

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

I have a few radio buttons which are displayed from mysql database. What I'm trying to achieve is when I click the submit button after selecting a radio button, it is disabled and when I click another radio button, the previously disabled one will be enabled and the currently selected radio button will be disabled.
My code for displaying the buttons:

```
    <form action="">
                        <?php
                        foreach ($sql->results() as $sql) {?>    
 <input type="radio" name="session_id" id="cur" value="<?php echo $sql->id; ?>">  <?php echo $sql->title;?><?php
}?>
<input type="submit" value="submit" onclick="set_type('a')">

                        </form>
                        <?php
                        }

                        ?>
```

I have tried to enable and disable some radio buttons on jsfiddle but it only works with different ids whereas my radio buttons have only one id.

**EDIT**: It has been made clear, ids must be unique. I have changed that.

Comment: Your radio buttons **CAN'T** have only one `id` . . . that's invalid HTML and it will keep many JS and jQuery functions from working normally.

Comment: OK, I thought so but can I use the values for this then?

Comment: Name should be the same to make them grouped, but id cannot be the same

Comment: I don't even know why I got a downvote. I just asked a simple question and got downvoted. It's really tough asking questions here.

Comment: Some people are really strict about question quality (too strict, in many people's opinions).  The best way to avoid downvotes is to (1) be very clear in what you are asking, (2) write up the question so that it is easy to read (e.g., good formatting of the code, all of the relevant code showing, etc.), and (3) show that you have made some effort in attempting to solve the problem on your own (i.e., "show your work"   :)   ).  Your question satisfies most of this pretty well . . . seemed like a resonable question to me . . .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm a little confused by exactly what you are trying to do, but I'll give a solution for each interpretation.   :)

You should be able to use this code to get the effect that you want, without needing to use any `id` or `name` attributes:

**Approach #1:** If you are wanting the buttons to be disabled when its associated radio button is selected, then use this code:

```
$(":radio").on("change", function() {
    $(":submit:disabled").prop("disabled", false);
    $(this).next(":submit").prop("disabled", true);
});
```

**Approach #2:** If the buttons are supposed to only disabled after they have been clicked, then use this code:

```
$(":radio").on("change", function() {
    $(":submit:disabled").prop("disabled", false);
});
```

. . . and let the `click` functionality that is (presumably) tied to the button, handle disabling it.

**Explanation:**  Basically, any time you click a radio button, you want to turn of the `disabled` property of any currently disabled buttons . . . the easiest way to do that is to select all of the disabled buttons and change the `disabled` property.  Once that is done, you can re-apply the `disabled` status to the one associated with the radio button (or, do that, when the button is clicked . . . whichever one matches what you are trying to accomplish   :)   ).

**Note:** this is also assuming that you don't have any other radio buttons and submit buttons on the page . . . if you do, you will need to "scope" the jQuery selectors.  The easiest way to do this would be to give your `<form>` element and `id` (I'll use "FORM_ID" for this example) and then update the code to this:

```
$("#FORM_ID").find(":radio").on("change", function() {
    $("#FORM_ID").find(":submit:disabled").prop("disabled", false);
    $(this).next(":submit").prop("disabled", true);
});
```

---

**EDIT:**

Based on your clarification, this code should accomplish what you are looking for:

```
$(":submit").on("click", function() {
    $(":submit:disabled").prop("disabled", false);
    $(this).prop("disabled", true);
});
```

Comment: What I'm trying to achieve is this. At first all buttons are enabled so when one is clicked and submitted, it becomes disabled while the others are still enabled. If I click another button then the previously disabled button will be enabled and the currently selected button will be disabled. For exampe, A,B,C are buttons and are all enabled. If I click A, it will be disabled while B and C are still enabled, then if I click on B, A will become enabled and B will become disabled.

Comment: Ahhhh . . . okay . . . I misunderstood.  I thought the radio buttons played some sort of part in the logic.  I'll update my answer.

Comment: With your help, I managed to get it working well: `<script>
     $(document).ready(function () {
   $(".me").click(function() {
   $(this).prop('disabled',true);
});
 });
</script>` I assigned the radio button a class and worked from there so now when I click a radio button, it disables while the rest remain enabled. Your previous code didn't really work well with the submit so I ust omitted the submit for the moment. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I have two suggestions.

1. you can't have same id for multiple elements in html. please change it
2. you can use css to achieve same above funtion